# Visual Studio Code Removing Items from System Path?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, path, environment-variables

I am opening a project in Visual Studio Code and it can't find npm, in spite of NPM being in my system path.

If I open a command prompt or a powershell prompt, and I type `env` I See it in my path.  If I open a terminal in VS:Code and type `env` it omits both: `/d/nodejs` and `/c/Program Files/Azure Data Studio/bin` from the list of items in my path.

I have tried rearranging all of my paths in my Windows Environment Variable editor dialog, and no matter the order, only these two items are missing.  So, I have validated that it is not other paths that could be causing issues in some sort of path parsing code.

Why would Visual Studio Code alter my path environment variable, removing node and its own path from the environment variable list?

If I move these items from my system path to my user path, it is able to find them but there are some other subtle issues with things not being found I haven't been able to figure out yet.

Note: These are the ONLY two items being removed.  And they are ONLY removed in VS:Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though there is other weirdness with moving the path to my user path from my system path, that was able to be worked around. So, my answer is: Move your nodejs path from your system path in Windows to your user path in Windows.